# oracle query - ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment but only in some versions of sql*plus

Tags: linux, oracle, client, sqlplus, ora-01652

This one has me rather confused. I've written a query which runs fine from my development client but fails on the production client with error "ORA-01652: unable to extend temp segment by....". In both instances, the database and user is the same. On my development machine (MS Windows) I've got SQL*PLUS (Release 9.0.1.4.0) and Toad 9.0 (both using version 9.0.4.0.1 of the oci.dll). Both run the code without errors.

However when I run the same file, against the same database, using the same username/password from a different machine, this time version 10.2.0.4.0 (from the 10.2.0.4-1 Oracle instant client) I get the error.

It does occur reproducibly.

Unfortunately I've only got limited access to the dictionary views on the database which is set up as read-only (can't even get an explain plan!).

I've tried working around the problem by tuning the query (I suspect that there is a large interim result set which is subsequently trimmed down) but have not managed to change the behaviour at either client.

It may be possible to deploy a different version of the client on the machine causing the problems - but currently that looks like downgrading to a previous version.

Any ideas?

TIA

### Update

Based on Gary's answer below, I had a look at the glogin.sql scripts - the only difference was that 'SET SQLPLUSCOMPATIBILITY 8.1.7' was present on the working client but absent on failing client - but adding it in did not resolve the problem.

I also tried

```
alter session set workarea_size_policy=manual;
alter session set hash_area_size=1048576000;
```

and

```
alter session set sort_area_size=1048576000;
```

to no avail :(

### Update 2

I managed to find the same behaviour, this time talking to an Oracle 8i backend. In this case the database was RW. That allowed me to confirm that the different clients were, as I suspected, generating different plans. But why????

Looking at the output of 'SHOW PARAMETERS' both clients reported *exactly the same settings*!

Comment: the instant client has less features than an Oracle runtime installation. Did you try the latter?

Comment: @Benoit: There are many oracle questions on SO with individual error code tags. The Error codes are useful tags,  by definition.

Comment: @skaffman, okay I will abide by this rule. Imho though a simple search will return the correct result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really an answer - but a bit more information....

Our local DBAs were able to confirm that the 16Gb (!) TEMP tablespace was indeed being used and had filled up, but only from the Linux clients (I was able to recreate the error making an oci8 call from PHP). In the case of the sqlplus client I was actually using exactly the same file to run the query on both clients (copied via scp without text conversion - so line endings were CRLF - i.e. byte for byte the same as was running on the Windows client).

So the only rational solution was that the 2 client stacks were resulting in different execution plans!

Running the query from both clients approx simultaeneously on a DBMS with very little load gave the same result - meaning that the two clients also generated different sqlids for the query.

(and also Oracle was ignoring my hints - I hate when it does that).

There is no way Oracle should be doing this - even if it were doing some internal munging of the query before presenting it to the DBMS (which would give rise to the different sqlids) the client stack used should be totally transparent regarding the choice of an execution plan - this should only ever change based on the content of the query and the state of the DBMS.

The problem was complicated by not being to see any explain plans - but for the query to use up so much temporary tablespace, it had to be doing a very ugly join (at least partially cartesian) before filtering the resultset. Adding hints to override this had no effect. So I resolved the problem by splitting the query into 2 cursors and doing a nested lookup using PL/SQL. A very ugly solution, but it solved my immediate problem. Fortunately I just need to generate a text file.

For the benefit of anyone finding themselves in a similar pickle:

```
BEGIN

DECLARE
CURSOR query_outer IS
    SELECT some_primary_key, some_other_stuff
    FROM atable
    WHERE....

CURSOR query_details (p_some_pk) IS
    SELECT COUNT(*), SUM(avalue)
    FROM btable
    WHERE fk=p_some_pk
    AND....

FOR m IN query_outer
LOOP
    FOR n IN query_details(m.some_primary_key)
    LOOP
        dbms_out.put_line(....);
    END LOOP;
END LOOP;

END;
```

The more I use Oracle, the more I hate it!

Comment: This is awful.  You're going to all this trouble and you really have no idea what's going on.  You absolutely, positively, need to see the explain plan.  If the DBAs won't help you out with this then you should hate them instead of Oracle.  Also, 16GB doesn't sound like a very large amount of temp tablespace.  It depends on the amount of data.  For example, if you're sorting a terabyte of data you'll need about a terabyte of temp tablespace.  (Where else will the intermediate results go?)

Comment: @jonearles: yes - it's not a good situation. But even if I could get the plans and demonstrate that they are different (which requires a lot of work and bypassing a lot of policy/opnion), that doesn't solve my problem - and I believe its likely that it could only be solved by Oracle themselves. Yes, 16Gb is only a lot relative to the amount of data - but there's not enough data to get this without a (at least partial) cartesian join. When I get the opportunity, I will be revisiting this - but for the purposes of the immediate objective the workaround is the more cost-effective solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

Years ago I worked on a DR database that was fully READONLY, and even the TEMP tablespace wasn't writable. Any query that tried to spill to temp would fail (even if the temp space to be used was pretty trivial).

If this is the same situation, I wouldn't be surprised if there was a login.sql (or glogin.sql or a logon trigger) that does an ALTER SESSION to set larger PGA memory value for the session, and/or changes the optimizer goal to FIRST_ROWS.

If you can, compare the results of the following from both clients:

select * from v$parameter
where ismodified != 'FALSE';

Also from each client for the problem SQL, try EXPLAIN PLAN FOR SELECT...
and SELECT * FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY);

See if it is coming up with different query plans.

Comment: Unfortunately, as per my post above "limited access to the dictionary views" (actually none of the v$ tables!) and "can't even get an explain plan!". Did try FIRST_ROWS - to no avail - but I'll see if I can tweak the PGA

Comment: @symcbean: I think Gary meant to compare the v$parameter values to see if they gave a clue that something was being set differently. Are you able to check for the existence of glogin.sql and login.sql files on each client machine?

Comment: @Alex Poole: Nope - I don't seem to have access to any of the v$ tables: ORA-04043: object v$parameters does not exist

Comment: @symcbean: I meant that given you couldn't see v$, can you at least check for the files that might be affecting the values and compare those instead, if they exist. Which I belatedly see you've now done *8-)

Answer (score 0):

A bit more information - I've run into the same problem connecting to a different database - this time an Oracle 8i. And I can get EXPLAIN plans.

Although in this case the query completed on both clients, it took 50% longer running from Linux sql*plus 10.2.0.4.0 vs WinXP sql*plus 8.0.6.0

As I suspected, the plans are different - but both are using the default settings on the client, both are using the same optimizer mode. It seems to think the plan generated from the Linux client has a lower cost than that from the XP client (although it does take longer to run). How does the optimizer prune the search path for potential plans?