# Performance issues with JDBC

Tags: oracle, jdbc

I'm currently facing an issue where a specific SQL-query is taking about 30 seconds to issue from within my Java application but <1 sec in a SQL-client (SQL Developer).

In the the question,
[Slow query in Java by JDBC but not in other systems (TOAD)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339549/slow-query-in-java-by-jdbc-but-not-in-other-systems-toad), it is suggested that using a PreparedStatement bound to java variables could make the query execute far slower than in the SQL-client (TOAD in that case) because Oracle is getting confused about which indexes to use. Could this be an issue with a PreparedStatement without parameters as well?

What could otherwise be the issue?

The query looks something like

```
select 
sum(col1),
sum(col2),
max(select ...)
from view_
where time_id = get_time_id(to_date('2010-10-10','yyyy-mm-dd'))
```

where view_ is a complex view containing aggregations of tables and other complex views. The query is executed as a PreparedStatement but without any parameters. It doesn't seem to make a difference whether we use prepared statement or just plain statements.

Since the execution plan is quite huge I can't post all if it here, but the relevant difference seems to be:

```
UNION-ALL 
TABLE ACCESS FULL GVC_WH.PLAYER_FACT_DAILY TABLE 37 6717151 596,934.317 19940 240 7621178231 19502
```

```
UNION-ALL 
TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID GVC_WH.PLAYER_FACT_DAILY TABLE 38 2657 236.120 2429 30 20544658 2428 
INDEX RANGE SCAN GVC_WH.PK_AGG_PLAYER INDEX (UNIQUE) 37 2657 16 1 638743 16
```

Where the first snippet is from when running it with the JDBC Thin Client and the second from when running it inside SQL Developer. It's not picking up the correct index when running as a statement (makes no difference whether I use a prepared statement or not) with the JDBC Thin Client. The time difference i 30 seconds for the first and 0.5 seconds for the second.

Could it be that using the function get_time_id prohibits the use of the index when used though JDBC, even though it is not function on the column and even though it seems to be working in SQL Developer?

Comment: Can you get and post the query plans for the two cases?  And just for clarity, are you being consistent about how you are measuring performance?  It is somewhat common to accidentally measure the time when SQL Developer returns the first row vs. the time that your Java code fetches the last row which may be substantially different.

Comment: I would start by looking at the execution plan (via dbms_xplan.display cursor) generated by each method (TOAD vs. Java).  That should tell you if the database is treating the queries differently.  If so, pay close attention to the predicates section as that will likely give you some clues as to why (e.g. implicit datatype conversion is occurring from the Java version and causing Oracle to not be able to use an index)

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976184/oracle-query-ora-01652-unable-to-extend-temp-segment-but-only-in-some-versions

Comment: Do you specify the date pattern parameter in your to_date call? I think the default pattern is dependent on your locale settings and might actually be different from java code or toad.

Comment: Does it make a difference if you split up your queries into `select get_time_id(to_date('2010-10-10','yyyy-mm-dd')) from dual` and then pass that into a prepared statement with `... where time_id = ?`

Comment: Hej!  Did you get any further on this? I see the same problem, where a query from SqlDeveloper (presumably using a thin jdbc driver) takes 0.7 seconds and the same query from my app server takes 30 seconds or more.

Comment: KarlP: No sorry, we didn't get any further on this detail. The warehouse was restructured before we got a chance to solve it.

Comment: And I moved on to another company about a year ago...

Answer (score 2):

I would try running a [trace](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL_Trace) on the database whilst using the application.

Then you should be able to see the query being run, and the actual execution plan. This will show you exactly what is going on, ie whether it is picking up the indexes or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is very possible you might be hitting problems with bind variable peaking due to the predicates being passed in.  Try running the query with the following to confirm (i.e. consistent run times)

```
alter session set “_optim_peek_user_binds”=false;
```

Are the stats up-to-date on all the objects?

As justin posted, as well, ensure you're measuring correctly as well.  Without the full query, it will be difficult to provide additional insight.

Comment: What variables are you referring to? As I said, the prepared statement is without parameters. Also the performance difference is orders of magnitude for fetching only a single row. The stats are up to date.

Comment: Depending on the value of CURSOR_SHARING parameter Oracle can force bind variables on the statements.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/initparams035.htm

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure someone hasn't set the property oracle.jdbc.defaultNChar=true

This is sometimes done to resolve unicode problems but it means all columns are treated as nvarchars. If you have an index on a varchar column, it won't be used because oracle has to use a function to convert the character encoding.

Answer (score 0):

just change Cursor_Sharing to EXACT if origin is FORCE